# Compréhension de "occasion de chute" dans un texte ancien

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Voici une citation de la Bible que j'affectionne particulièrement, [Matthieux 5.30](https://www.levangile.com/bible-LSG-40-5-30-complet-contexte-non):

> Et si ta main droite est pour toi une **occasion de chute**, coupe-la et jette-la loin de toi ; car il est avantageux pour toi qu’un seul de tes membres périsse, et que ton corps entier n’aille pas dans la géhenne.

Je m'interroge sur l'utilisation de "occasion de chute". Je l'aurais remplacé par une autre tournure, par exemple:

> Si ta main droite **te veux du mal**, ...

ou:

> Si ta main droite **représente un danger** pour toi, ...

A mes yeux, "occasion de chute" est ici incorrect et je ne comprends pas son utilisation (le texte date de 1910 mais la langue française n'a quand même pas changé à ce point). Auriez-vous une idée de pourquoi ça a été traduit ainsi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ce n'est pas l'occasion de chuter ou de faire une chute, mais c'est plutôt un terme de la religion chrétienne relié à la « faute grave contre Dieu » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chute)) et au dogme de la *chute originelle* (« événement par lequel l'homme, à l'origine, en commettant une faute grave contre Dieu, a perdu par là même l'amitié divine et l'état bienheureux dans lequel il se trouvait pour tomber dans sa misérable condition actuelle assortie de la souffrance et de la mort. », TLFi) ou *péché originel*, puis, par affaiblissement ([Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C2244)), à la faute morale, surtout en ce qui a trait à la chasteté, surtout en parlant d'une femme (TLFi) etc.

Vu que deux versets plus haut on parle d'adultère, l'*occasion de chute* c'est essentiellement l'*occasion de commettre un péché (mortel)*, celui-là, qu'évoque possiblement ces deux métaphores ; donc sans doute l'idée de se détourner (pour l'oeil) et de ne pas toucher (pour la main) plutôt qu'en coeur ou par leur truchement passer à l'acte et risquer l'« enfer » (la *géhenne*). *Ac.9* évoque aussi pour ce sens un titre célèbre d'un (très long) poème de Lamartine : [*La Chute d'un ange*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Chute_d%E2%80%99un_Ange)...

Comment: D'accord, donc il faut comprendre ce verset par "si quelque chose qui t'es vraiment cher te pousse à commettre un péché grave, mieux vaut t'en débarrasser que de risquer l'enfer" ? Je préfère l'interprétation laïque qui au final traduit le principe du moindre mal

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg Je ne suis pas spécialiste de ces questions et ce n'est pas le sujet du site, je m'intéressais surtout au vocabulaire avec _chute_ et à l'idée du sens par atténuation ou affaiblissement, mais c'est un texte d'un évangile avec un contexte de sermon sur différents commandements, dont « tu ne commettras point d'adultère » et le verset discute de ça à mon avis.